# Deep dive into Fragment replace transaction and system back key. The last fragment is not destroyed and still fully alive

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

1. `FragmentTransaction.add()` FragA on `id.content`
2. `FragmentTransaction.replace()`, `addToBackStack` FragB `id.content`
3. `FragmentTransaction.replace()` FragC `id.content`

Problem occurred as:

4. Click `System back` -> We'll see FragA being recreated but **FragC is still ALIVE**

It's due to as we click `System back` button, we revert the transaction of the second action on above. We'll `destroy` FragB rather than `destroy` FragC. FragC is alive and this is what I don't want.

One of the solutions is to implement a `backStackListener` in the Activity and as the `backStack` is 0, I then remove FragC by code.

Another one is before any `replace()` transaction, we call `popBackStack()` to remove previous transaction. And we apply `addBackStack()` on every subsequent transactions. However the downside is every time we call `popBackStack()`, it will invoke `onResume()` of previous Fragment which is also not pleasant.

Does anyone can kindly advise me any better solution on how to better cope with this? Really appreciate!!

Comment: Why are C and D not added to the back stack?

Comment: Because the flow I want to bring is just one "System Back Click", user will be led to the very first Fragment in the Activity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the approach I took is **removing FragC** when the `OnBackStackListener` detects the back stack count is changed to 0.